# Cheap SMA antenna for this ADS-B (aircraft info) receiver

Tags: antennas

[This](https://thepihut.com/products/flightaware-pro-stick-plus-usb-sdr-ads-b-receiver) looks like a lovely little toy, but I am unclear which antenna to use with it , and those on the site cost more than double the price of the receiver itself. It collects ADS-B (aircraft info) which I intend to process in software.

I am a pure software guy, with no knowledge of hardware, who is thinking of buying such a receiver to play around with it.

I live two miles from a major airport. Any idea if I could get away without an antenna (told you I know nothing of hardware ;-)? If not, what's the cheapest I can get, with post & package to the UK? I would prefer to use it indoors, if at all possible, rather than running a cable out to the garden, or even hanging it out of an upstairs window.

Anything else that I need to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UK amateur radio stores](https://www.google.com/search?q=UK%20amateur%20radio%20store) will have SMA antennas and connectors, as SMA is the most common connector for handheld transceivers. Please specify you want a UHF antenna for monitoring 1090 MHz [ADS-B/MLAT](https://flightaware.com/adsb/mlat/) aircraft transmissions. Conventional aircraft voice radio is 108-136 MHz AM; make sure to specify to the seller you need 1090 MHz. Also, make sure to get a standard male connector as there are 'reversed male' SMA connectors.

My Yaesu VX-5 HT receives aircraft UHF transmissions with its factory stock two metre rubber duckie antenna 20 miles LOS from PDX, but you can also obtain a connector and coax to attach it to an antenna in a window or an exterior omnidirectional antenna if that's not enough signal for you.

A vertical antenna is preferred as aircraft radios use vertical polarization.

How cheap is cheap? Here are rubber duckie 1GHZ capable SMA antennas [which attach to the receiver](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/d/digi-intl/uhf-300-mhz-to-1-ghz-antennas), a broader selection of [all that vendor's 1GHz capable antennas](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/rf-if-and-rfid/rf-antennas/875?FV=1883%7C378890%2C1989%7C0%2C-8%7C875%2C1850%7C417326%2C1850%7C417333%2C1850%7C419655&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&datasheet=1&pageSize=500), [another vendor's choices](https://www.everythingrf.com/search/all-antennas/filters?page=1&country=UK&stype=;Rubber%20Duck;&sindustry=;Aerospace%20%26%20Defense;&sfrequency_min=1000&sfrequency_max=1200), and [other selections](https://www.nearson.com/antennas.php?page_id=67&0=1&1=41). Put the receiver module near a windows on a pie plate or other flat metal object to provide a ground plane.

[1GHz UHF mag mount antennas](https://www.rfwiz.com/comtelco-a21wb698b-uhf-3dbd) can be ordered with the SMA connector to get it further away from the module if needed.

If you need cheaper, get an [SMA male to PL-259 female connector](https://www.moonraker.eu/sma-so239-male-sma-to-so239-socket) and a metre of stiff, solid copper bell wire at a hardware store, or out of your junk bin. Wrap the bare end of one piece of wire around the exterior of the PL-259 (larger end) connector and run that to a radiator or other ground. Take the rest of the wire, strip off a couple of cm on one end, fold the bare wire with pliers, and jam it into the interior of the PL-259; the other end goes straight up into the air. See illo at https://images.app.goo.gl/ku2TSmUQCsTuviYv7 ; more ideas are at 
https://survivalcomms.wordpress.com/2016/04/29/basic-antennas-for-vhf-uhf-field-communications-part-1/

And, [get a license](https://www.google.com/search?q=UK%20amateur%20radio%20license)! It's fun!

73 and best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 17 squids is a fair price, even if it is almost as much as that cheap receiver; but I can reuse the antenna if I move to a more expense receiver. Do I need a license if I am only receiving, not transmitting?

Comment: Oh, that is a legal question, and I'm a Septic, not a Subject of Her Majesty, God Bless the Queen. On this side of the Big Pond, it's absolutely legal.  Finding an 'Elmer', an licensed amateur radio operator willing to serve as a mentor, and asking them could resolve that; also, amateur radio stores might also help answer that,. I can say that https://www.ofcom.org.uk/manage-your-licence/radiocommunication-licences/aeronautical-licensing/licence-products does not say a receiver must be licensed, but other receivers (TV) I know must be licensed where you are.

Comment: Lolx! A "septic" who knows what a "septic" is :-)  It was you mentioning quid that threw me off. If it makes you fell better, round our manor we refer to "Shermans", rather than "septics" ;-)

Comment: Being Southron, I find I am uneasy at calling myself a Yankee, so I borrowed the Australian lingo 'Septic'.

Comment: I can follow your logic there,  unfortunately, to most of the world, you are all Yanks. Sad, but true :-(  When I run into one of our antipodean cousins, I can't avoid greeting him with a cheery "G'day, cobbler"

Comment: -1 for not mentioning matching wavelengths - SMA antennas are available for all kind of equipment, including WiFi and GSM - those won't work here.

Comment: @K7AAY meanwhile the question does not mention aircraft VHF and the product linked there receives at 1 GHz. And wavelength matching is still an issue which should be mentioned IMO.

Comment: I didn't check it precisely earlier, but you write about completely different stuff than the question.

Comment: So while I might've missed that part of your answer the -1 stays. It would be a very good answer IFF the question was about aircraft VHF AM. ADS-B is something different, at 1090 MHz.

Comment: @Jan Morniak Point well taken and answer rewritten. TY for catching my error.

Comment: @Jan Dorniak Point well taken and answer rewritten. TY for catching my error.